# Why "Last visit was at " + someDate.toLocaleDateString(); is a bad habbit?

Tags: javascript

When reading the reference about JavaScript on `Date` object from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), I get this note:

> You shouldn't use this method in contexts where you rely on a
>   particular format or locale.
>
> ```
> "Last visit: " + someDate.toLocaleDateString(); // Good example 
> "Last visit was at " + someDate.toLocaleDateString(); // Bad example
> ```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in other languages that way of writing the date could not make sense. In spanish, by example, you would say:

```
"La última visita fue el 27/03/2012 a las 14:04"
```

So if you just write "Last visit: ", you avoid the locale format of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Because it may wouldnt be legit english if you get a locale string.

It depends on which country you are in how the String may look